# How to install an older version of Google Play Services ? (SDK android)

Tags: android, service, sdk, playback

I'm trying to install an older version of Google play services than the actual one (r49) but without success.

I have to do this because the software that I'm using to develop android apps requires at least the r13, but it can't use the r49.
In the android studio, I can install the r12 (for Froyo) but it's not enough.
I have a .zip of the r28 that should work but I don't really understand how to install it, or maybe that's not possible?

Comment: I would guess that you need root access to deleted the exisiting Play Service before you can install an old version of that app or alternatively use custom rom that don't include Google Play Service by default.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer ! But I think you're talking about the app on the google play store ? I was asking for the thing that we can install in the android SDK

Comment: Nope I am really referring to that System app.

Comment: Ok, so I think I didn't understand, I'm using Android Studio to manage SDK, I remember that to install "Android support library", I had to download an older version, and to install it, I just had to put the files of the old version in the existing folder (with the recent version) in AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support and this method automatically refreshed the version number in Android Studio

Comment: I tried to do the same with google play services as I have found an older version on internet and it didn't work, in Android Studio Google play services appears as uninstalled... 
Sorry I don't really understand what I'm doing, I'm new in Android development..

Comment: I haven't tried it myself actually, You can't normally uninstall a system app so a root access + 3rd party uninstaller app might be needed after that try installing your desired Google Play Service. I also doubt that Android Studio will help you here cuz it will always suggest the latest version. You need to do it in your own risk though!